# What is the best way to set up MasterWork Dwarf Fortress on Linux?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

What is the best way to set up MasterWork Dwarf Fortress on Linux?

Some pages suggest to run Masterwork Dwarf Fortress.exe via Wine.

Others to run on other Win computer and then copy some files to Linux DF folder, although not specified what files is to copy.

Then, there's mdf-config script. But it doesn't know about any dependencies in settings and you can change only one setting at a time. One probably could get somewhere a full list of options and change them that way, but it is tedious.

Any better way? Please don't tell me to play on windows or wine. Only native Linux DF works with both CPU cores and I have a rather weak laptop.

Comment: DF can use multithreading? Time has come to install Linux I see. I would try to setup once under windows, then copy the whole directory to linux. Downside: to change settings, you have to repeat the whole process. DF config is notoriously complex. Perhaps you could use Wine just for setup, and run natively from the same install?

Comment: Be careful not to copy all the files from Windows MDF, because some of them are Win specific and will cause troubles. So first you have to figure out what these settings files are.

Comment: I disagree with downvoters. There is obviously some previous research, it is absolutely clear what the objective is, and for some people an answer would be definitely useful.

Comment: I know the question's a little dated, but if you're still interested in an answer this forum thread over at Bay12 may be of use.  Modders have recompiled some of the libraries on which MWDF depends for linux. http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=160636.msg7179453#msg7179453